# how to post TeX to Blackboard course?

Tags: collaboration

Has anyone figured out how to post TeX code to blackboard? My browser can't run the Java applet (I am running IE7 under administrative lockdown), so I don't know of a way to get blackboard to recognize

```
$T(n) \le cn - b$
```

as TeX markup.

Is there some other way to do this, like a shared link or copy-paste the image?

Comment: There is MathJax. Vist http://www.mathjax.org/.

Comment: I don't think this is on-topic here.

Comment: MathJax is not TeX! I don’t know, whether it will be useful for you, but let me point you to [MathJaX Help Forums](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mathjax-users).

Comment: I suggest you should ask this question on [_Academia Beta_](http://academia.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: http://library.uoregon.edu/scis/blackboard/faq/instructors/i65.html